# Function with varargs in constructor

Tags: scala, variadic-functions, first-class-functions

I am trying to get this working in Scala:

```
class MyClass(some: Int, func: AnyRef* => Int) {
}
```

The above code won't compile (why?) but the following does:

```
class MyClass(some: Int, func: Seq[AnyRef] => Int) {
}
```

That's OK but are the two equivalent? And if so, then how can I then use `func` inside `MyClass`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one (with varargs) works if you use parentheses:

```
class MyClass(some: Int, func: (AnyRef*) => Int)
```

The two forms of `func`, however are not the same.  The first version takes a vararg input, so you would call it like `func(a,b,c,d)`, but the second version takes a `Seq` as input, so you would call it like `func(Seq(a,b,c,d))`.

Compare this:

```
class MyClass(some: Int, func: (AnyRef*) => Int) {
  def something() = {
    func("this","and","that") + 2
  }
}
```

to this:

```
class MyClass(some: Int, func: Seq[AnyRef] => Int) {
  def something() = {
    func(Seq("this","and","that")) + 2
  }
}
```

Comment: Now, my question is what's the meaning of `()` wrapping around `AnyRef*`?

Comment: They're just parentheses to tell Scala that `AnyRef*` should be taken fully as the function's input.  Just like how `(1+2)*3` tell you that `1+2` should be taken fully as the first argument to `+`.

Comment: @nobeh The parenthesis around `AnyRef*` is the standard when specifying input parameters to a function. Their absence in the case of single-parameter function is a syntactic sugar exception.